# Dojo: Dynamically append search bar/ search field?

Tags: dojo, searchbar

does anyone know about any website or dojo code sample source for this kind of search citeria? I cannot find the relevant search bar info. Kindly advise any starting point where should i start from (e.g: what API should i use etc), sample or demo on this if available?

[Click here to view my drafted search bar design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKT6E.png)

Comment: Do you mean selecting an option from the dropdown and then create fields accordingly?

Comment: @Nicolas I Yup, exactly